# Convert an hex number into array

Tags: javascript, hex

I want to convert an hex number (let's say 0xABCDEF) into an array (0xABCDEF --> [0xAB;0xCD;0xEF]

I have tested this code:

```
  generateHexaArrayOf2FromHexaNumber (hexaNb){  
    var size = 1;
    var hexaNbTempo = hexaNb;

    while ((hexaNbTempo / 0xFF) > 1) {
      hexaNbTempo = hexaNbTempo / 0xFF;
      size++;
    }

    var hexaArray = new Array(size);
    for (var i= 0; hexaNb > 0; i++) {
      hexaArray[i] = hexaNb % 0xFF
      hexaNb = Math.floor(hexaNb / 0xFF) // round to lower
    }
    hexaArray.reverse();
    return hexaArray;
  }
```

Result is returned in ASCII not in hexa (have 
With 0xABCDEF as an entry it returns [173(=0xAD), 39(=0x27), 105(=0x69)]

Do you know why it is wrong and how to correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all `0xFF` by `0x100`. After all, you’re trying to make a base-256 array, not a base-255 one.

Also, you really don’t need the `size` calculation. You can also return `hexaArray.reverse()` directly. Also, use `push` instead of direct property assignment. Your code also left the array empty for input `0`, but wouldn’t you expect `[0]` as output?

Instead of `.push` you could also use `.unshift` and remove `.reverse()`.

Corrected code:

```js
function generateHexaArrayOf2FromHexaNumber(hexaNb) {
  var hexaArray = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; hexaNb > 0; i++) {
    hexaArray.push(hexaNb % 0x100);
    hexaNb = Math.floor(hexaNb / 0x100);
  }

  if(!hexaArray.length){
    hexaArray.push(0);
  }
  
  return hexaArray.reverse();
}

console.log(generateHexaArrayOf2FromHexaNumber(0x1)); // => [ 1 ]
console.log(generateHexaArrayOf2FromHexaNumber(0xabcdef)); // => [ 171, 205, 239 ]
console.log(generateHexaArrayOf2FromHexaNumber(0xabcdef).map((x) => x.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))); // => [ "ab", "cd", "ef" ]
console.log(generateHexaArrayOf2FromHexaNumber(0xdeadbeef).map((x) => x.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))); // => [ "de", "ad", "be", "ef" ]
console.log(generateHexaArrayOf2FromHexaNumber(0x0).map((x) => x.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))); // => [ "00" ]
```